# Double dash in Centos vs OSx shebang

Tags: node.js, shebang, babel-node

I have the following `./run` file with +x mode.

```
#!/usr/bin/env babel-node --
require("generator/run.js")
```

which serves as a entry point for a task manager (for a static site generator).

I call it like `$ ./run someTask --someFlag` and it works just fine on my local machine (OS X) with `process.argv` like:

```
[ 'node',
  '/Users/username/Projects/projectname/run',
  'someTask',
  '--someFlag' ]
```

Hovewer, when I try the same `$ ./run someTask --someFlag` command on the machine with CentOS, I'm getting an error:

```
/usr/bin/env: babel-node --: No such file or directory
```

Though babel-node is surely installed and manual call:

```
$ /usr/bin/env babel-node --
```

works fine as well. I know that the problem is somehow caused by double dashes – removing them *removes the bug*. But I need those dashes to separated my own task flags, otherwise they are getting consumed by `babel-node` I searched for "double dash shebang" here and on Google, got no answers.

Of course, I can change the call approach to `babel-node ./run ...` but I'd like to keep `$ ./run someTask --someFlag` syntax if that's possible and learn why this happens. Is there a principal difference in shebang handling between Unix and Linux or it's a difference between Node.js on both machines?!

P.S.

Both machines have the same version of Node.js, babel-node and project files.